# How can i tell if a window is in fullscreen from command line

Tags: command-line, display, resolution

So I found that with `wmctrl -F -r "SomeWin" -b add,fullscreen` I can make a window fullscreen, now i want to run a cron so that it stays open, but also verifies that it's fullscreen.

Is there something that can tell me if it's fullscreen or not? or do i have to compare the window size with the screen size. If so, with `wmctrl -G -l` I get the window size, but I have nothing to compare it with, `wmctrl -d` says `0  * DG: 2880x1800  VP: 0,0  WA: 65,24 1375x876  N/A`, the resolution is 1440x900, so none of those are it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like

```
xprop -name TitleGoesHere _NET_WM_STATE | grep -q _NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN
```

should do it.  Note that the window title used by `xprop` is the legacy ISO8859/1 title, so Unicode characters won't work; it may also need to be the full title and not just a substring.  `xprop` itself can be used in interactive mode to get the right string; run

```
xprop WM_NAME
```

and wait for the cursor to change to a crosshair, then click on the window.